# Is it possible to code logic for an ethereum wallet?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nft, opensea

As a disclaimer, I am not a solidity developer, so this question might be a bit naive, but any help would be appreciated.

I want to know **if I can use a smart contract to code logic for an ethereum wallet address such that any funds sent to the address are automatically distributed to one or more different addresses** (using ethereum from the initial payment to cover gas for the redistributive payments). I am doing this as a way of getting around a limitation of Opensea royalty payments (i.e. royalties can only be paid to one wallet). Heretofore, I have manually sent royalty payments to the various members of my team, but I would like to automate the process in a trustless fashion. Even if I had to approve the transfers, trustless redistribution would be much better than what I'm doing now.

I don't need a detailed explanation, just an answer as to whether or not such a thing is possible and maybe the name of a resource or two I could look into.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have a similar question, A kind reddit user gave me an answer. Here it is (credit to u/thePsychonautDad):

> You can implement this with a smart contract.
> When a smart contract receives value, the special function `receive` is called:
>
> `receive() external payable { ... }`
>
> You can setup a contract that stores the addresses in an array, then on `receive()`, you send `msg.value/addresses.length`  to each address in the array.
>
> I wrote a simple version of the contract, so you can build on it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity 0.8.10;

contract splitter { // To store the list of wallet owners address[] public owners; // Public, but you can set as private if you wish

// An event to known when a payment has been received by this wallet
event paymentReceived(uint256 value, address sender);

// Constructor: Executed once at contract creation
constructor(address[] memory _owners) {
    owners = _owners; // Store the wallet owners (immutable after contract creation)
}

// Triggered when a payment is received:
receive() external payable {
    uint i;
    uint l = owners.length; // How many addresses to pay
    uint256 value = msg.value/l; // How much to send each address
    // Pay each of them
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        payable(owners[i]).transfer(value);
    }
    // Trigger the event
    emit paymentReceived({
        value:  msg.value,
        sender: msg.sender
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Be aware that there are ways to transfer eth to a contract without triggering the `receive` or `fallback` method: https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#forcibly-sending-ether-to-a-contract

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you!